# Jsoup - How to select the element below target element?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a list of `.span6>h6` elements that may or may not exist depending on if a user has filled out that option on their profile page. I want to get the value of each of these options (if they exist).

The value of these options is stored inside each of the `.span6>h6` elements as a `<pre>` tag. I need to get each one of the `h6` elements, read its contents and for each option store the value which is contained in the element below it, in the correct place.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <h6>Gender</h6>
    <pre>Male</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <h6>Location</h6>
    <pre>Someplace</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <h6>Occupation</h6>
    <pre>Figuring out this problem</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <h6>Interests</h6>
    <pre>Figuring out this problem</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another in depth example, in case my first one was confusing. If the `h6` element exists with the contents "Gender", get the next element `<pre>` and store the text Male somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test it, but I think the following can work:

```java
Elements els = Jsoup.parse(html).select( ".span > h6" );
for (Element el : els) {
        String option = el.text();
        String value = el.nextElementSibling().text();
}
```

`.nextElementSibling()` will get the first element after your `h6`; if you think you'll need to be specific and get only `pre` siblings, you can replace that line with the following:

```java
String value = el.siblingElements().select( "pre" ).first().text();
```